# Unable to go from on page to another using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am working on a project for which I have to scrape a website "http://app.bmiet.net/student/login" after logging into it. I have successfully loged into the website however, after logging in I reach the dashboard i.e. http://app.bmiet.net/student/dashboard. I have to scrape data from http://app.bmiet.net/student/attendance. I am not sure how to go from the dashboard to the attendance link and thats what I need help for. I am still learning to use scrapy and so I am not sure if this can be done or not. Please Help me with my code and do tell me what my mistake was. The code is given below.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser



class spidey(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spidyy'
    start_urls = [
        'http://app.bmiet.net/student/login'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('form input::attr(value)').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
            'csrf_token' : token,
             'username' : '//Username//',
             'password' : '//password//'
        }, callback = self.start_scrapping)

    def start_scrapping(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        all = response.css('.table-hover td')
        for x in all:
            att = x.css('td:nth-child(2)::text').extract()
            sub = x.css('td~ td+ td::text').extract()
            yield {
                'Subject': sub,
                'Status': att
            }
```

NOTE: Removed Username and Password for obvious reasons

This is what I get when I crawl my spider.

```
2020-03-21 19:38:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-03-21 19:38:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-03-21 19:38:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-03-21 19:38:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://app.bmiet.net/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-03-21 19:38:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://app.bmiet.net/student/login> (referer: None)
2020-03-21 19:38:53 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://app.bmiet.net/student/dashboard> from <POST http://app.bmiet.net/student/stud
ent-login>
2020-03-21 19:38:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://app.bmiet.net/student/dashboard> (referer: http://app.bmiet.net/student/login)
2020-03-21 19:38:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: you need to make sure you are actually logged in, `open_in_browser` will do that

Comment: Open in browser will open the dashboard in the browser right? how can I go from thr Dashboard to the attendance link ?

Comment: I don't have login information,but to move to another page you simply extract the link and `yield scrapy.Request(attendance_link,callback=self,parse_att)`

Comment: And where will I include this line of code ? In the beginning or start_scrapping ?

Comment: in `start_scraping`

Comment: What exactly is parse_att ? Also will this be the first line in start_scrapping ?

Comment: `parse_att` create a function to scrape the attendance link